# mysql class not found in dynamic web maven project?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, servlets

First I created simple java maven project in eclipse. Then I added mysql dependency in pom.xml. Then I wrote a function where I was creating connection and fetching some data from mysql db. I wrote main function in that class to test it. It was working.

Then to accept user request I have added dynamic web facet in maven. Then I wrote a servlet. In that servlet I just copied the code which I wrote in main function(previously defind class).But when I hit the servlet, the user console prints com.mysql.jdbc.driver not found. How is that even possible. Because it's working in other class.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the jar that I need to connect to MySQL 5.5 should have been mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar but not mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar. Secondly, this jar is not available in maven repository so I needed to manually add it to my local maven repository and then added it as a dependency in my pom.xml.

Adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar to the local maven repository by

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Libraries\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar -DgroupId=mysql -DartifactId=mysql-connector-java -Dversion=5.1.15-bin -Dpackaging=jar

and then adding the following dependency to pom.xml of the project.

```
<!-- MySql 5.5 Connector -->   
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.15-bin</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just googled and found this `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>`. Is this not what you need?